# How to avoid jQuery data() to convert string to number

Tags: jquery

I have following sample code:

```
<li class="item" data-my-number="012">Some text</li>
```

When I run this code:

```
var value = $('.item').data('myNumber') 
//value is 12
```

But I want it to be "012".
How to do that?

Comment: Can you post your complete code? Based on the switch between my-number and myNumber, you're paraphrasing your code and there may be other elements you're missing too.

Comment: It turns out that the solution is pretty simple:
Just call attr() instead of data() because attr method keeps the value as string instead of trying to convert it to some object...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the `attr()` method.

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr()` instead of the `.data()` shortcut to avoid the conversion into a number.

From the JQuery docs:

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null)

http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Answer (score 0):

jquery code you want  [**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxst5/17/)

```
alert($('.item').attr('data-my-number'))
```